# Stop batch file if more than 1 zip file in specific directory

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I need a rule for a batch file so if there's more than 1 zip file in a specific directory the batch will abort and give a message.
Is it possible in ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, just amend `%SPECIFIC_DIR%` to your specific directory:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET SPECIFIC_DIR=.
SET COUNT=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B %SPECIFIC_DIR%\*.zip') DO SET /A "COUNT+=1"
IF !COUNT! GTR 1 (
    ECHO More than one .zip file, aborting!
    EXIT /B
)
ECHO Just one .zip file, continue...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Real life saver =)

Comment: @AndréSilva: You're welcome! Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/214366), if it saved your life :)